# Método não é reconhecido dentro da classe

Tags: php

Estou criando algumas classes em `php` e estou com a seguinte duvida:
para métodos `get` e `set` em `php`, montei da seguinte forma:

```
class User
{
    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';

    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = encript($password);
    }

    public function getPassword(){
       return $this->password;
    }

    function encript($data){
        return sha1($data);
    }
}
```

porem quando chamo assim `$user->setPassword(1234)` da erro `função encript() não definida`, onde esta o erro? não sei muito de `php` mas já fiz dessa forma em outras linguagem e geralmente funciona, qual o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em php uma função é diferente de um método. Ao invocar funções basta chamar o nome. Com métodos é necessário dizer quem é dono dele, fora da classe é o objeto, dentro da classe se usa o `$this`.

Mude:

```
$this->password = encript($password);
```

Para:

```
 $this->password = $this->encript($password);
```

Comment: estranho, mas obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: @HebertdeLima sem o `$this` o PHP acha que vc está chamando uma função `encript()` de fora da classe, essa abreviatura que vc citou na pergunta funciona em outra linguagens como java por exemplo, no PHP a sintaxe fica um pouco mais longa :P